# S3 error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, parquet

I used following dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <javac-source.version>1.8</javac-source.version>
    <javac-target.version>1.8</javac-target.version>
    <hadoop.version>3.2.1</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-avro -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-azure-datalake</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.762</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Set following configuration:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key","key_id");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key","key");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.NAME);
    conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
```

used following Path:

```
new Path("s3a://bucket_name/" + filename)
```

and I also tried to set `HADOOP_HOME`,it does not help

I get always the following error:

```
20/04/15 17:55:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/04/15 17:55:13 WARN impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
20/04/15 17:55:13 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
20/04/15 17:55:13 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:477)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:822)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:223)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:266)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:489)
at Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

The same credential with s3n worked on the 2.8.2 version of hadoop. But know for 3.2.1 s3n is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to write to S3 using the Hadoop's `s3a` client, the local filesystem is used to creating temporary files. To be able to use the underlying filesystem, native support based on the operating system has to be added.

This exception states the same,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
```

This being the Windows operating system, you would need the [`winutils`](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils).

1. Download the `winutils.exe` binary and other required files as per your Hadoop version from [here](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils).
2. Set the environment variable `%HADOOP_HOME%` to point to the directory where these binaries were installed.

**Read more:** [Hadoop2 - Windows Problems](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems)